# Xcodeアプリ制作におけるデータ管理について

Tags: swift

Xcode6(Swift)でゲーム系アプリを作る場合、ゲームデータやセーブなどの機能はCoreDtaで作成するのがいいのでしょうか？
それともゲーム系に特化しているSpriteKitやcocos2d-Swiftを使ったほうが楽にできるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

結論から言うとセーブデータの構造によると思います。

CoreDataはDatabaseのように同系のデータが複数大量に出てくる場合は便利ですが、単一のデータで間に合う場合はUserDefaultかXmlなどのファイルを利用するのが良いと思います。（あくまで個人的な見解です）

Answer (score 3):

Core Dataは、オブジェクト化されたリレーショナルDBですから、そういう機能が必要なデータであれば、Core Dataをつかうのもありでしょうが、一般には、ゲーム・データのセーブ（中断して再開するための）には、必要としないでしょう。

Comment: そうなんですね！それではCoreDataではなく、SpriteKitのフレームワークやcocos2d-Swiftのほうが良いということですね……回答ありがとうございました。

Comment: @らりん SpriteKitやcocos2d-Swiftにはセーブ機能は無いですよ。

Comment: お手数おかけして申し訳ないのですが、セーブ機能のある(もしくはXcodeでセーブ機能が使える)フレームワークや詳しい記述の記載しているウェブサイトなど、具体的な方法を教えて頂けると幸いです。

Comment: 一般化したデータのセーブ機能の為のフレームワークなどはないでしょう。だから、あなたのセーブしたいデータが、どんな構造なのか、どのような性質なのかを、明らかにしないと、誰も回答できないでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

一番簡単な方法はNSUserDefaultsやNSKeyedArchiverを使うことです。

Comment: その二つについての特徴と、何が異なるかを知りたくなりました。